# Why I am getting nil while unwrapping an Optional value when I eliminated all nil_s?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

Hey I have problem placing variables.
How can I use variables those that I use lets say in function "A" in another function "B". In another word use variables from Function "A" in function "B"

I have function("A") to set notification text:

```
let sentence = textField.text! + " Some beautiful text!"

let firstWord = sentence.characters.split(" ").first.map(String.init)

LocalNotificationHelper.sharedInstance().scheduleNotificationWithKey("someText", title: "see options(left)", message: sentence, date: deadlinePicker.date, userInfo: userInfo)
```

Now I gotta call the `firstWord` inside another function("B") in that variable here:

```
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName(firstWord)
```

I tried to add those first variables `sentence` and `firstWord` in `ViewDidLoad` and outside of class but for nothing. I keep getting error `"found nil while unwrapping"`
I call the function where is variable `predicate` when user tap notification action button like this.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "functionWhereIsPredicateVariable:", name: IDENTIFICATOR, object: nil)
```

Do I have to store the `firstWord` into `NSUserDefaults` or do I have to do it in another way??

Comment: check out the outlet of textField

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Could you try explaining it in a bit more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save your name to userinfo

```
let userInfo = ["url" : "Hello","name":nameField.text!]

//Set notification
                LocalNotificationHelper.sharedInstance().scheduleNotificationWithKey("TempCo", title: "see options(left)", message:nameField.text!+" Your contact needs to be deleted!", date: deadlinePicker.date, userInfo: userInfo)
```

then you can get it from notification's object and post it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if identifier == DELETECONTACT {
        print("delete action - tapped")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DELETECONTACT, object:notification.userInfo)
```

And you can get name from notification's object

```
//**DELETE CONTACT FUNCTION**\\
func contactDelete(notification : NSNotification){
let name:String? = notification.object?["name"]  as? String
```

Comment: If I try to get name from notification's object I get nil while unwrapping. But this is definately best solution if I get it to work

Comment: you shoule ensure that you had set UILocalNotification's  userInfo correctly

Comment: I tried with the same exact userinfo you just set. Hmm.. Do I have to create separate userInfo array also maybe? I tried to print userInfo also and it gives me nil also.

Comment: as i saw from your demo,you have not set userinfo accurately.

Comment: such as `func notificationWithTitle (`

Comment: all  `func scheduleNotificationWithKey`  except first

Comment: My notifications are set in the right way. What do you mean? My notification has userInfo it is [NSObject: AnyObject].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114708/discussion-between--and-tarvo-maesepp).

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets of variables with the same name, one declared at class scope and one declared with function scope. In function A you are setting the values of the function scope variables but in function B you are accessing the class scope variables which are still nil.

To fix it get rid of the "let" in function A where you are using sentence and firstWord.

Comment: I did it but still I get the nil. I edited my question with some more details. I do nut understand how it is nill if it has the value even console shows me the optional value. How it can be so hard to find your own error in code :D

Comment: I said to remove the let in function A, in your question it is still there. Update your question with the latest complete code.

Comment: Did it. I even tested if my array contains "firstWord" in function "B" and it does contain it but it do not delete given firstName. It just keeps the last entered "firstName" as variable